# ESP8266+uart, block a esp

Tags: lua, uart, esp8266, nodemcu

I have a problem with my esp. When I try connect to stm32 by usart esp has 'diffrent state' and must again flash.

Firmware:

[image]

And my program:

```
print("plik")
uart.alt(1)
uart.setup(0, 9600, 8, uart.PARITY_NONE, uart.STOPBITS_1, 1)
uart.on("data", 25,
  function(data)
    print("receive from uart:", data)
    if data=="quit" then
      uart.on("data") -- unregister callback function
    end
end, 0)
```

Effect:

[image]

Can you tell me where is any fail that esp does`t react?

Comment: `"When I try connect to stm32 by usart esp has 'diffrent state' and must again flash."` I don't understand what you meant with that sentence. What is the "different state"? Why must you flash again? What's your hardware setup?